# One of my Rails routes requesting favicon.ico

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just added `resources: :favorites`, nested inside `resources: :deals`, to my Rails app. All of a sudden, visiting the `deals/deal_slug/favorites/new`, after it renders, fires off a GET request to `deals/favicon.ico` which of course activates the `show` route, which fails to find anything with the slug of `favicon.ico`.

It appears to ONLY be the `favorites/new` route that causes this request, and I've tried commenting out all of `favoritescontroller#new` as well as the `new` view, with no change.

Commenting out `link href="../../favicon.ico" rel="icon"` in my `layout` fixes it of course, but I'd love to keep that in my layout and figure out why the heck this problem JUST started!

My routes file:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # what are these??
  get 'regions/index'
  get 'regions/show'

  root "deals#index"

  resources :deals, param: :slug do
    resources :favorites
  end
  resources :favorites

  get 'my-deals', to: 'deals#my_deals', as: :my_deals_path
  resources :regions, param: :slug, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :deals, only: [:index, :show], param: :slug
    # resources :deals, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :destroy]
  end

  resource :preferences
  ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections {|inflect| inflect.irregular 'preferences', 'preferences'} # fix route helper paths so that form_for works
  get '/preferences/delete_airport/:airport_id', to: 'preferences#destroy', as: 'delete_home_airport'

  resources :vacations

  get 'pry', to: 'application#pry'

  # ------- DEVISE STUFF --------

  devise_for :users, controllers: { 
    omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks', 
    preferences: 'users/preferences',
  }

  devise_scope :user do 
    get "/sign_out", to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: 'user_sign_out'
    get "/sign_in", to: 'users/sessions#new', as: 'user_sign_in'
    get "/sign_up", to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: 'user_sign_up'
    get "/user/preferences", to: 'users/preferences#index', as: 'user_preferences'
    get "/user/preferences/edit", to: 'users/preferences#edit', as: 'edit_user_preferences'
    patch "/user/preferences/:id/edit", to: 'users/preferences#update'
  end

  devise_for :admins, path: 'admin', controllers: { sessions: 'admins/sessions' }

  devise_scope :admin do
    get "/admin", to: 'admins/sessions#portal', as: 'admin_root'
    get "/admin/sign_out", to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: 'admin_sign_out'
  end

end
```

FavoritesController:

```rb
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    prefs = current_user.preferences
    @favorite = Favorite.new deal: Deal.find_by(slug: params[:deal_slug]), preference_id: prefs.id
  end

  def create
    @favorite = Favorite.create(favorite_params)
    redirect_to preferences_path
  end

  def favorite_params
    params.require(:favorite).permit :preference_id, :deal_id, :comment
  end
end
```

Comment: To start, you should use `resources :favorites`, not `resources: :favorites`. The same with deals. Please post your routes and your favorites_controller.

Comment: I'll include that code. I am indeed using `resources` rather than `resources:`, I just forgot the format when writing my question. Sorry/thanks!

Comment: What gem are you using for your slugs?

Answer (score 0):

The request for the favicon icon is made by the browser, your code does not trigger that request.

The problem is your favicon href, you are making it relative to the current path: "../../favicon.ico" instead of absolute "/favicon.ico". You'll get the same problem if you have other routes with more than 2 levels since the route is relative.

You should add the favicon.icon somewhere on your public folder and point at it with an absolute path instead. If the icon is in `/public/favicon.ico` then configure the layout's favicon tag with `href="/favicon.ico"`, if you put the icon somewhere else like `/public/icons/favicon.ico` then change the link tag to `href="/icons/favicon.ico"`.

Comment: That makes sense, but it's weird that this only happens on that one route.

Comment: Do you have more routes with more than 2 levels? if you have less levels then "../../" just stops at the root. I'd bet that if you have more long routes like `deals/deal_slug/favorites/new` with a lot of levels you'll see a similar request.

Comment: ah, that does make sense!